# Using AngularJS model on a tabset

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a tabset with two options where I bind data from a JSON file using angular, what I want is to **log** in my console the name of the tab I'm clicking, so I was thinking using a "model" but I dont know if that is correct.

This is my tabset

```
<tabset>
  <tab heading="tab1">
    <div class="panenl-body">
        content
    </div>
  </tab>

   <tab heading="tab2">
    <div class="panenl-body">
        content
    </div>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

I've seen something like this:

```
<div class="radio radio-text" ng-init="topTable.value='topCategory'">
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="topTable.value" value="topCategory" ng-change="updateTotals(topTable.value)">TY Top 30 Categories</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="topTable.value" value="topSupplier" ng-change="updateTotals(topTable.value)">TY Top 10 Suppliers</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="topTable.value" value="topBrand" ng-change="updateTotals(topTable.value)">TY Top 10 Brands</label>
</div>
```

So you can do something when you click on a radio button, something similiar I want to do but with the tabset.

Comment: Are the values fixed in the tabset or do you have an array or something that the name or what ever will be coming from? Are you using `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want but of course you can do something like this with a tabset:

```
<tabset>
  <tab heading="tab1" ng-click="tabClicked('This is name 1')">
    <div class="panenl-body">
      content
    </div>
  </tab>

  <tab heading="tab2" ng-click="tabClicked('This is name 2')">
    <div class="panenl-body">
      content
    </div>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.tabClicked = function(value) {
  console.log(value);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your time =)

Comment: Yep, no problem :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where the 'tabset' directive is defined, however assuming you have access to the directive definition:

```
app.directive('tab', function() {
   return {
       restrict : 'E',
       link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
           element.on('click', function() {
               console.log('This is tab: ', attrs.heading);
           }
       }

   }
});
```

and in your HTML:

```
<tabset>
  <tab heading="tab1">
    <div class="panenl-body">
      content
    </div>
  </tab>

  <tab heading="tab2">
    <div class="panenl-body">
      content
    </div>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

This way we're not using `ng-click`, seeing as you're not updating any scope or controller object, there's no need to trigger a digest cycle using `ng-click`.